# Implementing Image Click, User Selection, and Label Creation on TextView in Jetpack Compose with Composable Navigation and Accurate Positioning

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, textlabel

Clicking on an image (within a Image composable) should open a new screen (using `NavHost` and `NavController`).
The new screen should display a list of users (using LazyColumn and  `rememberScrollState()` for smooth scrolling).
Upon selecting a user (by clicking a Button or similar composable), the app should navigate back to the original screen.
A label (using Box or Text composables) should be created and positioned at a specific point on the TextView within the original image.
I have attached an image to illustrate the desired functionality.

Technical challenges I am facing:

- Positioning the label accurately on the TextView.
- Handling the navigation between screens.
- Managing the user selection state.

This is the one of reference that I found while doing R&D to print image offset click point

[How to detect what image part was clicked in Android Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71482003/how-to-detect-what-image-part-was-clicked-in-android-compose)

**What is current challenge for me is to print or recompose UI with latest text label to screen**

[image]

Comment: Share a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

To create a UI like this you should apply a constraint layout in compose for reference please check
https://github.com/cengiztoru/ConstraintLayout-JetpackCompose/tree/master.

`StateFlow` in ViewModel will help you to maintain the state of your list.